# storing more than 2 power 31 on a 32-bit system

Tags: c, math

I have to write a program that can calculate the powers of `2 power 2010` and to find the sum of the digits. eg:

```
if `2 power 12 => gives 4096 . So 4+0+9+6 = 19 .
```

Now i need to find the same for `2 power 2010.`

Please help me to understand.

Comment: So you have to do up to 2^2010?

Comment: yes, I have to calculate the value of 2^2010 and should store and display the same.

Comment: This is most likely a trick question, since no c base type can hold a number with all of its 605 digits. Ask someone who is proficient with maths.

Comment: you'll either need an arbitrary-length integer arithmetic library, or you need to implement arbitrary-length integer arithmetic yourself to do this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic

Answer (score 37):

Here's something to get you started:

```
char buf[2010]; // 2^2010 < 10^2010 by a huge margin, so buffer size is safe
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.0Lf", 0x1p2010L);
```

Comment: `0x1p2010L` ?? that's not valid C

Comment: I stand corrected; I've never heard of floating point constants. Go figure.

Comment: +1: Just tried it on codepad and compared against Python bignum. How the @#%@# does that work, when the floating point number doesn't contain 2010 bits of state?

Comment: 2^2010 has 12 bits of state, not 2010 bits of state.

Comment: right, but how does printf/snprintf manage to produce an exact result?

Comment: Via expensive (in space and time) arithmetic, basically just like what you'd perform doing it by hand. Actually it should be noted that `printf` is not required to show correct digits past `DECIMAL_DIG` places, but good implementations always show exact results, especially for floating point values which are actually integers (no fractional places).

Comment: Wow, I am amazed ! I never knew about such [hexadecimal floating point constant](http://www.exploringbinary.com/hexadecimal-floating-point-constants/). +1 !

Comment: this does not calculate the sum of the digits in base 10 artithmetic.
printf will not print out that many digits!  Why so many upvotes? this is not a valid solution.

Comment: It will definitely print that many digits. They're not required to be *correct digits*, but I already noted that (and the fact that, in practical situations, they are correct) in the comments.

Comment: Oh and as for not doing the summing, I was trying to leave OP with a little bit of work to do rather than doing OP's full homework assignment...

Comment: Inspite all the scores - this is quite a useless answers. Least important thing you do with numbers is print them! It is more of a question of how do you manipulate them!

Comment: @Dipan: I beg to differ. It's a path to solving OP's homework problem in a clever way. Of course it doesn't generalize to other computations, but the problem was a specific one not a general one.

Answer (score 18):

You have to either use a library that supplies unlimited integer length types (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum ), or implement a solution that does not need them (e.g. use a digit array and implement the power calculation on the array yourself, which in your case can be as simple as addition in a loop). Since this is homework, probably the latter.

Comment: See the example here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Mathematics.aspx for a string based implementation. Since you only need addition - the only tricky thing is the carry step.

Comment: BTW, a simpler implementation can involve a binary representation (i.e. a 2011 long bit array) and repeatedly performing division by 10 on it (implemented as long division), storing the reminder in the array and storing the sum of answers.

Answer (score 9):

Knowing 2^32, how would you calculate 2^33 with pen and paper?

```
2^32 is 4294967296

4294967296
*        2
----------
8589934592

8589934592 is 2^33; sum of digits is 8+5+8+9+...+9+2 (62)
```

Just be aware that 2^2011 is a number with more than 600 digits: *not that many to do by computer*

Answer (score 7):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org/) is perhaps the best, fastest free multi-architecture library for this. It provides a solid foundation for such calculations, including not only addition, but parsing from strings, multiplication, division, scientific operations, etc.

For literature on the algorithms themselves, I highly recommend [The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms by Donald Knuth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896842). This book is considered by many to be the best single reference for the topic. This book explains from the ground up how such arithmetic can take place on a machine that can only do 32-bit arithmetic.

If you want to implement this calculation from scratch without using any tools, the following code block requires requires only the following additional methods to be supplied:

```
unsigned int divModByTen(unsigned int *num, unsigned int length);
bool isZero(unsigned int *num, unsigned int length);
```

divModByTen should divide replace num in memory with the value of num / 10, and return the remainder. The implementation will take some effort, unless a library is used. isZero just checks if the number is all zero's in memory. Once we have these, we can use the following code sample:

```
unsigned int div10;
int decimalDigitSum;

unsigned int hugeNumber[64];
memset(twoPow2010, 0, sizeof(twoPow2010));
twoPow2010[63] = 0x4000000;
// at this point, twoPow2010 is 2^2010 encoded in binary stored in memory

decimalDigitSum = 0;
while (!izZero(hugeNumber, 64)) {
    mod10 = divModByTen(&hugeNumber[0], 64);
    decimalDigitSum += mod10;
}

printf("Digit Sum:%d", decimalDigitSum);
```

Comment: A agree with GMP way, own implementation probably won't be as fast, mathematically proven as GMP. Unless one need it for school or something, then I would get down to binary instead of this.

Comment: I never recommend GMP for serious use since it has the rather fatal flaw (for a general purpose library) of aborting your program on out-of-memory errors. It's okay for playing around.

Answer (score 6):

This takes only a few lines of code in Delphi... :)

So in **c** must be the same or shorter.

```
function PowerOf2(exp: integer): string;
var
  n     : integer;
  Digit : integer;
begin
  result := '1';
  while exp <> 0 do
  begin
    Digit := 0;
    for n := Length(result) downto 1 do
    begin
      Digit := (ord(result[n]) - ord('0')) * 2 + Digit div 10;
      result[n] := char(Digit mod 10 + ord('0'))
    end;
    if Digit > 9 then
      result := '1' + result;
    dec(exp);
  end;
end;
```

-----EDIT-----

This is 1-to-1 c# version.

```
string PowerOf2(int exp)
{
    int n, digit;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("1");
    while (exp != 0)
    {
        digit = 0;
        for (n = result.Length; n >= 1; n--)
        {
            digit = (result[n-1] - '0') * 2 + digit / 10;
            result[n-1] = Convert.ToChar(digit % 10 + '0');
        }
        if (digit > 9)
        {
            result = new StringBuilder("1" + result.ToString());
        }
        exp--;
    }
    return result.ToString();
}

int Sum(string s)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += s[i] - '0';
    }
    return sum;
}

for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
{
    string s1s = PowerOf2(i);
    int sum = Sum(s1s);
     Console.WriteLine(s1s + " --> " + sum);
}
```

Comment: he was asking for a solution in C

Comment: @Tilo: Yes I know, but I don't want to do his homework and Pascal code is simple to understand. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can calculate and print 2<sup>2010</sup>:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void AddNumbers(char* dst, const char* src)
{
  char ddigit;
  char carry = 0;

  while ((ddigit = *dst) != '\0')
  {
    char sdigit = '0';

    if (*src != '\0')
    {
      sdigit = *src++;
    }

    ddigit += sdigit - '0' + carry;

    if (ddigit > '9')
    {
      ddigit -= 10;
      carry = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      carry = 0;
    }

    *dst++ = ddigit;
  }
}

void ReverseString(char* s)
{
  size_t i, n = strlen(s);

  for (i = 0; i < n / 2; i++)
  {
    char t = s[i];
    s[i] = s[n - 1 - i];
    s[n - 1 - i] = t;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char result[607], tmp[sizeof(result)];
  int i;

  memset (result, '0', sizeof(result));
  result[0] = '1';
  result[sizeof(result) - 1] = '\0';

  for (i = 0; i < 2010; i++)
  {
    memcpy(tmp, result, sizeof(result));
    AddNumbers(result, tmp);
  }

  ReverseString(result);
  printf("%s\n", result);

  return 0;
}
```

You can now sum up the individual digits.