# How many time do I need to add 2 to get the value equivalent to 2 raised to 1000

Tags: data-structures, logic

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Prob 16.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16) I am planning to take  two dimensional array to store the calculate and store the results. 
To calculate 2 raised to 3, I need to add 2, 4 times
To calculate 2 raised to 4, I need to add 2, 8 times
Similarly, how many times will I need to add 2 to the result to get 2 raised to 1000?
Which data structure will be best suited for this (preferably in C++)?
And what would be a good algorithm to solve this in C++?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7651229/968261).

Comment: `nx2 = 2^m`, so, `n = (2^m)/2`. To get, 2^1000, you need to add 2 for 2^999 times. This answers your first question. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. In order to get n (any even number) you always needs to add together 2 n/2 times; to get 2^n you need to add 2 together 2^(n-1) times. This tells you nothing.

Can I give you the hint that you don't need to calculate the total to answer the question?

Comment: @BhaskarUpadhyayula: Thanks. Yes that is what I wanted. Thats a partial answer. I am also looking to store the numbers. Would anyone know which datastructure should I use (preferably c++) ?

Comment: Hint: `2^2 = 4 = 2+2`, `2^3 = 8 = 4+4`, `2^4 = 16 = 8+8`. Use a one-dimensional array for the digits.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Yes Please

Comment: why don't you just `sum([int(x) for x in str(2**1000)])` in python ;)

Comment: @strmax, Python is a great language. Unfortunately, I dont know Python. P.s, I edited my little bit to make it more clear.

Comment: @SameerShah When I said "Can I give you the hint..." the rest of the sentence was the hint.

Comment: @DJClayworth: LOL, silly me. So you are suggesting never to calculate the entire total, just split up the large numbers in columns (of arrays) and just do add and carry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to exactly the same kind of problem has been previously shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7749847/968261). The number of decimal digits in 2<sup>1000</sup> is `ceil((1000 + 1) * log10(2)) = 302`. One more character will be needed for the string terminator, `'\0'`. `* log10(2) = * 0.3` can be approximated with `/ 3 = * 0.3(3)`.

Comment: This worked. One more question, can you please explain how does the AddNumber functions works.

I tried stepping through the AddNumber  function especially the foll code:

'   if (ddigit > '9')
    {
      ddigit -= 10;
      carry = 1;
 
      carry = 0;
    }'


 and all I could see is that values were doubling like 8 was becoming 6 (without the carry). I would really be nice to understand this awesome function so that I can reuse it later.

Comment: It works the same way as you'd do it with pencil and paper. It adds digits of the two numbers going from the least significant to the most significant digits, propagating the carry and stopping when '\0' (string terminator) is encountered (there're two checks for it). The only difference is that it actually manipulates with C's characters, not digits, which is why '0' (numeric value of character '0') is subtracted in one place. Nothing fancy, just school arithmetic.

Comment: See a [video](http://www.khanacademy.org/video/addition-4?playlist=Arithmetic), if you missed the concept.

Comment: Oh, I got that, thanks. However,  the pointers were kind of obscuring the real value on the debugger inside the function. The only difference from the actual addition is that your code is adding from MSB to LSB. Also, you are just copying over the value in a temp variable to double it. So if it was something like 3 raised to 2010, then you would have to copy the values in 2 different variables and then perform the addn.

If you had changed the *dst++ and *src++ to *dst-- and *src--  and then changed the addition accordingly, then you would not have to reverse the entire char array in the end.

Comment: @SameerShah: you got it wrong. The addition proceeds from LSB to MSB. How would you propagate carries if it was done the other way around??? The reversing is done because we customarily write and print numbers from the most significant digits to the least significant digits. The adding function was implemented in a way to support arbitrarily long numbers and have a simple interface. If you don't like it for whatever reason, change it. Transform it to a "doubler" instead of "adder", if you want to. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking what data structure you should use to hold the digits of the integer value of the result of 2<sup>1000</sup>.  Instead of reinventing the wheel, I'd recommend using something like Java's [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class that will hold arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: Thank you but I would prefer something in c++. I dont know java

Comment: @SameerShah That was just an example.  Most languages will have a library that you can use.  For C++ you can use GMP. http://gmplib.org/

Comment: That is a good suggestion. I want to use GMP as the last resort. I am thinking anything like vector, list could suffice for what I am doing. But, I am not sure

Comment: @SameerShah: have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7749847/968261)?

Comment: @Alex: This was the language, DS and methodology that I was looking for, just arrays and char var, beautiful! I got the result. Thank you.
Quick question though, how do you know that the size of the result would be somewhere along 607 or something. I know that there is a way to calculate it.

Comment: @SameerShah: there're `log10(2)` decimal digits in every bit, so `(2010 + 1) * log10(2) = 605.4`, you round it up to 606 and reserve one more character for the string terminator, `'\0'`. That's how I got 607. You could also reserve a little more by calculating `(2010 + 1) / 3 + 1 = 671`.

Comment: @Alex: Great, can you please repost our comment as the answer, I would like to mark your response as the answer